# Парсинг блоков при помощи BS4 и requests

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup

нужно спарсить блоки BTC, ETH, USDT, ,USC
Вот сайт: https://nominex.io/ru/markets/

Как парсить информацию с таблицы я знаю, но я не знаю, как спарсить инфу с других блоков типа ETH.

Возможно ли без selenium это сделать?

Comment: Ну на первый взгляд там всё скриптами генерится, так что без selenium вряд ли

Comment: А как можно подключить скрипты в код и прочитать сайт?

Comment: Повторяю - используйте `selenium`, тут много примеров найдёте поиском, про него каждый день вопросы задают.

Comment: @ДмитрийВинокуров, для этого нужен скриптовый движок, например selenium, если есть Qt4/Qt5, то можно через QWebPage/QWebEnginePage

Comment: Дело в том, что я делаю парсер через телеграм, и парсер будет работать круглосуточно, так, что надо как-то сделать это через bs4 и requests